# Cannot make Keycloak work inside docker-compose with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak as an authentication server for my Spring Boot application. It's working just fine when I lauch keycloak in a standalone docker and just run my application locally, but now I'm trying to make everything work inside a docker-compose.

When I'm running my docker-compose I end up with the following error when trying to call my API :

```
o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from http://localhost:8080/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

ishelp is the name of my realm, I can access my keycloak interface on http://localhost:8080.
I believe the error comes from the lack of between localhost and realms on the url Spring is trying to reach. I have a 404 on http://localhost:8080/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration but I can reach http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration.

I added **127.0.0.1 keycloak** to my *host* file and I have the following configurations files :

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: postgres-db
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - web

  postgres-keycloak:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-keycloak
    volumes:
      - pgdata-keycloak:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - web

  user-service:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: user-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - web

  keycloak:
    image:  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres-keycloak
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - web

volumes:
  pgdata:
  pgdata-keycloak:

networks:
  web:
```

application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/ishelp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloak:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=ishelp
keycloak.resource=user-service
keycloak.credentials.secret={{my_secret}}
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.ssl-required=external

server.port=3000
```

KeycloakConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    private String SERVER_URL;

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    private String REALM;

    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    private String CLIENT_ID;

    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
    private String CLIENT_SECRET;
    
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public Keycloak keycloak() {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(SERVER_URL)
                .grantType("client_credentials")
                .realm(REALM)
                .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And finally KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurer.java :

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurer extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

}
```

Thanks for you help !

Edit 1: As requested, here's my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.isep</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-service</name>
    <description>Authentication server for the project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>13.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Edit 2: The logs of the error. I believe Spring should try to load http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration but I can't make it happen.

```
user-service         | 2022-04-25 12:46:22.105  INFO 1 --- [nio-3000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
user-service         | 2022-04-25 12:46:22.105  INFO 1 --- [nio-3000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
user-service         | 2022-04-25 12:46:22.109  INFO 1 --- [nio-3000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
user-service         | 2022-04-25 12:46:22.226  WARN 1 --- [nio-3000-exec-2] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from http://localhost:8080/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration
user-service         |
user-service         | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
user-service         |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:230) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:182) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getRealmInfoUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:246) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:107) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:67) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.1.jar!/:17.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.1.jar!/:17.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

EDIT 3 : Adding more logs, I think it could be useful but I can't get how and why

```
user-service         | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.input" is null
user-service         |  at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3165) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904) ~[na:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:66) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.sendRequest(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:97) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.getPublicKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:63) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.getPublicKey(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:121) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:111) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:67) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.1.jar!/:13.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.1.jar!/:17.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.1.jar!/:17.0.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar!/:5.6.1]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:na]
user-service         |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
```

Comment: Please share all the logs

Comment: See updated post

Answer (score 1):

According to your dependencies, you are using keycloak 17.0.1. For `17.0.1` version, `keycloak.auth-server-url` should be `http://keycloak:8080`. Try changing it. It should solve your issue.

Also, why are using `13.0.1` for keycloak-adapter-bom? It should be consistent with all other depedencies.

Comment: It definitely helped ! I noticed I was using the wrong version of Keycloak in my docker-compose. So now I put http://keycloak:8080 in my config, but I still have the same issue. Connection refused. But if I try to access the URL in my browser, I can see the JSON Spring is trying to get.

Comment: But shouldn't Spring try to get http://keycloak:8080/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration instead of http://localhost:8080/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration ?

Comment: @Artcann Which Keycloak URL spring is loading now? Also, could you try using the 15.x.x keycloak version throughout your pom?

Comment: Spring is trying to load the following url : localhost:8080/realms/ishelp/.well-known/openid-configuration
This one is the right url cause I can see the information Sprint need when I go on the url with my browser. I updated my post with more logs you should check it maybe it could help

Comment: @Artcann did you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that Spring boot app coudn't find keycloak service by provided hostname, because you didn't define it properly. So docker generated own custom hostname. If you will define hostname in correct way everything will be work perfect. You have to define hostname for your keycloak instance and provide this hostname to application.properties. Your code should look like this:

```
...
    keycloak:
        image:  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
        hostname: keycloak
...
```

In your application.properties you already used hostname `keycloak` so I belive it should work for you.

application.properties for keycloak > 18 version

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloak:8080
```

sub path `/auth` is not more mandatory

Answer (score -1):

I see that you specified client_credentials. This means there is no browser involved which makes it simpler to troubleshoot. Please try from the command line to make sure that your Keycloak config supports this grant type:

```
   curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/XXXXXXX/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=XXXXX' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=XXXXX' \
    --data-urlencode 'scope=email' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Replace XXX with your values. Spring would need to make the same call but with a keycloak host.

Comment: Yeah I already added the entry in etc/hosts. But I thinks the real problem is that Spring doesn't reach the right url, and I can't find why and how to change that.

Comment: I tried it and I can reach this url, but Spring is not calling the right url, as I said in my post, it's missing the /auth before the /realms, and I can't find how to change that. I specified the right base url but it looks like Spring doesn't use it.